# How to generate a customer in a group on Square Connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, square-connect

I'm automatically generating customers from a form on my client's restaurant site. He's using Square for his POS and marketing, but would like our form to automatically send customer data to his system. The following code works, but it would be vastly improved if it would automatically append a group to those customer records.

The API is vague about the handling [CustomerGroupInfo](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/?q=group#type-customergroupinfo) with customer creation.

*Gemfile*

```
gem 'square_connect'
```

*Tracker*

```
class Tracker < ActiveRecord::Base
  require "square_connect"
  ...
  def send_info(email, note)
    api = SquareConnect::CustomerApi.new
    api.create_customer(ACCESS_TOKEN, {
      email_address: email,
      reference_id: code, # Tracker variable
      note: note
    })
    self.update_attributes used: true,
                           email: email
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

At this time, customer groups are just read only via the API.